# React: setting array object in setState

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, setstate

I am trying to reset an array using the setState method in React. In the constructor I have set tile_arrays to null initially.

The first console.log() produces the desired array of N Tile objects after the nested for loops finish. When setState is called and the subsuquent console.log() after, the state is still null and was not updated.

I am not trying to append new information to the states array, but replace it entirely.

```
createTileArray(){
        let new_array= [];
        let size = this.state.size;
        for(let row = 0; row < size; row++){
            
            for(let column = 0; column < size; column++){
                
                if(row === 0 || row === 1){
                    //Player 1
                    new_array.push(new Tile(column, row, true, 1))
                }
                else if(row === size - 1 || row === size - 2){
                    //Player 2
                    new_array.push(new Tile(column, row, true, 2))
                }
                else{
                    //Empty Tile
                    new_array.push(new Tile(column, row, false, 0))
                }

            }
        }
        console.log("Tile to be set into the state", new_array)
        this.setState({
            tile_arrays:new_array
            
        },
        () => console.log("Updated Tiles: ", this.state.tile_arrays))
    }
```

Comment: this.setState is asynchronous, you can't log it after setting it. Try logging it in render.

Comment: You might want to give something like [this](https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296) a read.

Comment: I fixed the console.log() but the state is still not being updated with the new array, any thoughts?

Comment: So the first `console.log` is not matching the second `console.log`?
You can edit your question and add a new section below the current information to represent your current code-state.

Comment: Ok I made an edit on the code to be a little more readable and implemented the new console.log change. To be a little clearer, the first console.log is meant to showcase that it has an array of Tile object(which it does log correctly). The second console.log is meant to showcase the state now has the new updated array instead of its initialized null state. After a closer look it doesn't even look like that second console.log is outputting anything.

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is asynchronous, but it does allow a callback.

```
 this.setState(
   { tile_arrays: tile_array },
   () => console.log("Updated Tiles: ", this.state.tile_arrays)
 )
```

Comment: So it doesnt set the tile_arrays properly and I'm not sure why

Answer (score 1):

Copied and pasted your code in a snippet to demonstrate the comment I made one hour ago.

> Try logging it in render

```js
class Tile {
  constructor(column, row, something, player) {
    this.column = column;
    this.row = row;
    this.something = something;
    this.player = player;
  }
}
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    size: 3,
  };
  createTileArray() {
    let new_array = [];
    let size = this.state.size;
    for (let row = 0; row < size; row++) {
      for (let column = 0; column < size; column++) {
        if (row === 0 || row === 1) {
          //Player 1
          new_array.push(new Tile(column, row, true, 1));
        } else if (row === size - 1 || row === size - 2) {
          //Player 2
          new_array.push(new Tile(column, row, true, 2));
        } else {
          //Empty Tile
          new_array.push(new Tile(column, row, false, 0));
        }
      }
    }
    console.log('Tile to be set into the state', new_array);
    this.setState({
      tile_arrays: new_array,
    });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.createTileArray();
  }
  render() {
    //was that so difficult?
    console.log('tile arrays', this.state.tile_arrays);
    return (
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, undefined, 2)}</pre>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little testing, I have found a solution. In my initial constructor for the component, instead of setting

```
tile_arrays:null
```

I set it to equal an empty array

```
tile_arrays:[]
```

The problem seems to be fixed and working now.